# Find the root view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

Activity -> ViewPager -> Fragment -> RecyclerView -> RecyclerViewAdapter -> ViewHolder -> MyView

if I do `View rootView = myView.getRootView();`. The rootView I get back, where is it coming from?

Answer (score 0):

ITs the topmost view.  It basically calls getParent until the parent is no longer a view, then returns the last view.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I understood as much before asking the question. So in the path I laid out, is it going to return the layout of the Activity? I look at the source code for View and I don't see where that recursive calling is taking place. Can you point me to something concrete that backs the obvious assumption?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#View.getRootView%28%29